# Issue when uploading past 8MB?

Tags: uploads

So I downloaded a plugin that sets your `max_file_upload` to 250 MB and I set my php.ini to the same. I own server so it is not a server issue - I have many apps that upload very large video files.

When I am trying to upload a file, no matter how large (up to 200MB tested), it shows that the file uploads in the progress bar.  If it were going over the upload limit I get an error telling me the file is too big - but this is not the case.

Instead of a second or two after hitting 100% on the progress bar, it times out with "HTTP error".  Seems like a memory issue with WP so I added `define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '250MB');`

Doesn't work.  Let me know what else I can do.  It is not an issue with the server.  When I do phpinfo it shows 250M and I have uploaded many files larger than 8M on other apps on the same server.

Name of the plugin is PBP Increase upload limit.  Also when I do not have the plugin on I cannot download big files at all.   With the plugin, I can download the file - but when it gets to the "crunching" progression it faults out with the HTTP error.

Comment: What is the plugin you are using? Have you tried that plugin's support forum?

Answer (score 1):

In your php.ini make sure you're changing both of the following lines.

```
upload_max_filesize = 250M
post_max_size = 250M
```

If you are using FastCGI as your PHP engine you'll also need to up its limit in Apache. Try adding FcgidMaxRequestLen to your VirtualHost (see http://httpd.apache.org/mod_fcgid/mod/mod_fcgid.html#fcgidmaxrequestlen for more info on the directive).

Finally, if you're on NGINX you might need to set

```
client_max_body_size 20M;
```

You'll do this under the *http* section of nginx.conf (see http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#client_max_body_size for more information)

Comment: Chris - I have tried the php.ini file several times and it never works.  I am on W2008 so don't know if that makes a difference.  The plugin allows the initial download to start but it doesn't complete.

Comment: Are you using IIS or another web server?

Answer (score 0):

I had a heck of a time figuring this out because I had WordPress installed on Windows Server 2016 IIS and nearly all instructions and plugins related to hosted Linux installs.  I created a short video of the solution you can see here:

https://www.urtech.ca/2018/04/solved-wordpress-on-iis-change-upload-file-size-limit-avoid-http-error/

I hope this helps.

Comment: Answers should be self-explanatory, and not depending on external links. So it would be best to include all necessary information into the answer. Thanks.